# Na fila de Publicações de baixa qualidade, o título diz que estamos analisando uma pergunta, mesmo quando o post sendo analisado é uma resposta

Tags: bug, status-pronto, filas-de-análise

Na fila de Publicações de baixa qualidade, quando a publicação sendo analisada é uma resposta, o texto diz que é uma pergunta.

---

Exemplo: [nesta análise](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/351091), se clicarmos no título ("Problema ao pegar o valor de um input radio"), somos levados para [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/527963/problema-ao-pegar-o-valor-de-um-input-radio/527997#527997) (indicando que se trata de uma resposta). E os demais textos da tela também indicam tratar-se de uma resposta (exceto por um deles, que diz ser uma pergunta):

[image: revisão com texto incorreto, diz que a resposta é uma pergunta]

Repare que em dois lugares está correto (indica que é uma resposta), mas justamente no texto que a meu ver parece ser o "principal" (até por estar em fonte maior, etc), é dito que é uma pergunta.

---

Já quando a publicação sendo analisada é uma pergunta, o texto fica correto. [Exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/351044):

[image: revisão com texto correto, quando é pergunta]

Comment: No traducir parece que em inglês é apresentado com duas strings separadas e estão traduzidas corretamente, deve ser bug do sistema e não da tradução: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXl3e.png

Comment: Outro detalhe, no SOen parece que o nome da fila é "Low quality answers", isso foi uma mudança feita há 22 dias, provavelmente esta causando BUG, pois a mudança "me parece" que deveria ter sido feita só no SOen, mas parcialmente ela afetou os sites "primos" (como o SOpt), comentei pra staff: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release#comment1234732_369013

Comment: Parece que era um erro de tradução, que entretanto corrigi [aqui](https://pt.traducir.win/strings/14087). Deverá estar corrigido no próximo build.